# Let the minimum edit length depend on a post's age and answered status

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

For a very old post (especially a question that has accepted/upvoted answers, or any answer to such a question) there is not much point fixing minor spelling errors at the expense of putting it back to front page.

On the other hand, a question that is only a couple of minutes old is on front page anyway, so in this case a minor bump due to something simple yet severe like a missing semicolon in a MWE (assuming that is not the origin of the question's problem) should be much more acceptable.

Therefore I propose the minimum edit length starting at 1 char during the first few minutes and increase it in an adequate manner (to be elaborated upon) to a rather high number for questions older than a specific age.

Comment: Why do you want to start with strict rules? If there was a problem that trivial edits for old posts are accepted, we could start with displaying statistics like age, accepted status, etc. on the review page to guide reviewers.

Comment: @oberlies Aren't they already displayed? Or were you being sarcastic?

Comment: Right, this information is already displayed. And still you think that we need hard thresholds?

Comment: @oberlies That information helps reviewers to _reject_ useless bump-edits. But my suggestions helps them by simply refusing too trivial edits to be even _suggested_, and IMHO the perceived triviality / importance of an edit varies with time

Answer (score 0):

An example could be something like this:

```
Post Age | Min. edit length
---------+----------------------
< 5 min  |  1
5-30 min |  2
.5-2 h   |  4
---------+----------------------
         |    | min. edit length
Question |    | in presence of
  Age    |    | upvoted/accepted
         |    | answers
---------+----+-----------------
2-24 h   |  8 |  16
1-7 d    | 16 |  32
1-4 w    | 32 |  64
> 4 w    | 64 | 128
```

Note that in this example, for answers younger than 2 hours their own age is considered (they caused a bump due to their mere creating anyway), while after that the question's age (always larger than the answer's age) is considered even for answer edits in order to make unnecessary edits/bumps less likely.